# Print the summary of an lm or fastLm() model without printing the coefficients

Tags: r, lm, summary

Using my own dataset I have way too many Coefficients. 
I simply want to print the summary without(or partly) printing the coefficients.

Example script:

```
lm.fit <- lm(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Petal.Length)
summary(lm.fit)
```

Output:

```
> summary(lm.fit)

Call:
lm(formula = iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Petal.Length)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.24675 -0.29657 -0.01515  0.27676  1.00269 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        4.30660    0.07839   54.94   <2e-16 ***
iris$Petal.Length  0.40892    0.01889   21.65   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4071 on 148 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:   0.76, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7583 
F-statistic: 468.6 on 1 and 148 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Desired output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Petal.Length)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.24675 -0.29657 -0.01515  0.27676  1.00269 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4071 on 148 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:   0.76, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7583 
F-statistic: 468.6 on 1 and 148 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I know I can call with `summary(lm.fit)$names` selected from the `names` mentioned below. But what I need is the opposite. The summary *without* coefficients.

```
> names(summary(lm.fit))
 [1] "call"          "terms"         "residuals"     "coefficients" 
 [5] "aliased"       "sigma"         "df"            "r.squared"    
 [9] "adj.r.squared" "fstatistic"    "cov.unscaled"
```

Is this possible? And if so, how?

---

Edit: I actually needed this for fastLm from the `RcppArmadillo` package. 
I just expected the output of `lm()` and `fastLm()` to be the same. The code provided by @LyzandeR works perfectly for `lm()`.

Using @LyzandeR's example I have googled and created the following snippet which replaces the print summary provided with the RcppArmadillo package.

```
print.summary.fastLm <- function(x, ...) {
    ## Alternate print summary
    ## Prints without coefficients
    cat("\nCall:\n")
    print(x$call)
    cat("\nResiduals:\n")
    print(x$residSum)
    cat("\n")

    #printCoefmat(x$coefficients, P.values=TRUE, has.Pvalue=TRUE)
    digits <- max(3, getOption("digits") - 3)
    cat("\nResidual standard error: ", formatC(x$sigma, digits=digits), " on ",
    formatC(x$df), " degrees of freedom\n", sep="")
    cat("Multiple R-squared: ", formatC(x$r.squared, digits=digits),
    ",\tAdjusted R-squared: ",formatC(x$adj.r.squared, digits=digits),
    "\n", sep="")
    invisible(x)
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I slightly changed the `print.summary.lm` function and just commented out the parts that print the coefficients (the commented lines of code can be seen below):

```
print.sum2 <-
  function (x, digits = max(3L, getOption("digits") - 3L), symbolic.cor = x$symbolic.cor, 
            signif.stars = getOption("show.signif.stars"), ...) 
  {
    cat("\nCall:\n", paste(deparse(x$call), sep = "\n", collapse = "\n"), 
        "\n\n", sep = "")
    resid <- x$residuals
    df <- x$df
    rdf <- df[2L]
    cat(if (!is.null(x$weights) && diff(range(x$weights))) 
      "Weighted ", "Residuals:\n", sep = "")
    if (rdf > 5L) {
      nam <- c("Min", "1Q", "Median", "3Q", "Max")
      rq <- if (length(dim(resid)) == 2L) 
        structure(apply(t(resid), 1L, quantile), dimnames = list(nam, 
                                                                 dimnames(resid)[[2L]]))
      else {
        zz <- zapsmall(quantile(resid), digits + 1L)
        structure(zz, names = nam)
      }
      print(rq, digits = digits, ...)
    }
    else if (rdf > 0L) {
      print(resid, digits = digits, ...)
    }
    else {
      cat("ALL", df[1L], "residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!")
      cat("\n")
    }
    if (length(x$aliased) == 0L) {
      #cat("\nNo Coefficients\n")
    }
    else {
      if (nsingular <- df[3L] - df[1L]) {
        #cat("\nCoefficients: (", nsingular, " not defined because of singularities)\n", sep = "")
      }
      else {
         #  cat("\nCoefficients:\n")
      }
      coefs <- x$coefficients
      if (!is.null(aliased <- x$aliased) && any(aliased)) {
        cn <- names(aliased)
        coefs <- matrix(NA, length(aliased), 4, dimnames = list(cn, 
                                                                colnames(coefs)))
        coefs[!aliased, ] <- x$coefficients
      }
      #printCoefmat(coefs, digits = digits, signif.stars = signif.stars, na.print = "NA", ...)
    }
    cat("\nResidual standard error:", format(signif(x$sigma, 
                                                    digits)), "on", rdf, "degrees of freedom")
    cat("\n")
    if (nzchar(mess <- naprint(x$na.action))) 
      cat("  (", mess, ")\n", sep = "")
    if (!is.null(x$fstatistic)) {
      cat("Multiple R-squared: ", formatC(x$r.squared, digits = digits))
      cat(",\tAdjusted R-squared: ", formatC(x$adj.r.squared, 
                                             digits = digits), "\nF-statistic:", formatC(x$fstatistic[1L], 
                                                                                         digits = digits), "on", x$fstatistic[2L], "and", 
          x$fstatistic[3L], "DF,  p-value:", format.pval(pf(x$fstatistic[1L], 
                                                            x$fstatistic[2L], x$fstatistic[3L], lower.tail = FALSE), 
                                                         digits = digits))
      cat("\n")
    }
    correl <- x$correlation
    if (!is.null(correl)) {
      p <- NCOL(correl)
      if (p > 1L) {
        cat("\nCorrelation of Coefficients:\n")
        if (is.logical(symbolic.cor) && symbolic.cor) {
          print(symnum(correl, abbr.colnames = NULL))
        }
        else {
          correl <- format(round(correl, 2), nsmall = 2, 
                           digits = digits)
          correl[!lower.tri(correl)] <- ""
          print(correl[-1, -p, drop = FALSE], quote = FALSE)
        }
      }
    }
    cat("\n")
    invisible(x)
  }
```

Now if you run:

```
> print.sum2(summary(lm.fit))

Call:
lm(formula = iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Petal.Length)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.24675 -0.29657 -0.01515  0.27676  1.00269 

Residual standard error: 0.4071 on 148 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:   0.76, Adjusted R-squared:  0.7583 
F-statistic: 468.6 on 1 and 148 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

It works exactly as you want it to.

Comment: Thanks, I actually needed it for fastLm but managed to do that myself using your example. I've also changed the title and posted what I've done so it works for both lm and fastLm!

Comment: For clarification so you don't think my option works for both! Yours works for `lm()`, mine works for `fastLm()` now :)