# Printing only the coefficient table of the summary of an lm with significance marks

Tags: r, lm, summary, pretty-print

Consider a linear model in R:

```r
frame      <- data.frame(y=rnorm(100), a=rnorm(100), b=rnorm(100))
frame["c"] <- frame["y"] + 2*rnorm(100)
model <- lm(y ~ a + b + c, data=frame) #lm
```

Calling `summary(model)` produces the following output in the console:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ a + b + c, data = frame)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.13983 -0.54933  0.01975  0.44218  2.38721 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.060624   0.088597  -0.684   0.4955    
a            0.009773   0.088171   0.111   0.9120    
b            0.157979   0.080924   1.952   0.0538 .  
c            0.188913   0.039788   4.748 7.17e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8464 on 96 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2146,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1901 
F-statistic: 8.745 on 3 and 96 DF,  p-value: 3.478e-05
```

I would like to only print the coefficients part, the exact complement of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32989379/print-the-summary-of-an-lm-or-fastlm-model-without-printing-the-coefficients), like so:

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.060624   0.088597  -0.684   0.4955    
a            0.009773   0.088171   0.111   0.9120    
b            0.157979   0.080924   1.952   0.0538 .  
c            0.188913   0.039788   4.748 7.17e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

This is not possible by calling `coef(summary(model))` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56518871/how-to-print-just-coefficients-of-lm), since that produces

```
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.060624   0.088597  -0.684   0.4955    
a            0.009773   0.088171   0.111   0.9120    
b            0.157979   0.080924   1.952   0.0538  
c            0.188913   0.039788   4.748 7.17e-06
```

which lacks the significance marks on the right. Preferably, the solution doesn't involve re-programming the entire `summary()` body as suggested in the thread above.

Comment: It doesn't matter much in this case, but you might want to get in the habit of using `set.seed()` when you post an example that involves pseudo-random numbers ...

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, true, spotted that too late. Luckily I've designed the experiment such that you should get high significance for `c` regardless of random number generation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `printCoefmat`.

```r
printCoefmat(coef(summary(model)))
            Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.019348   0.089500  0.2162    0.8293    
a           0.023219   0.101134  0.2296    0.8189    
b           0.085962   0.085934  1.0003    0.3197    
c           0.190828   0.042007  4.5427 1.615e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```